Expo sqlite database rejection
i have been working on  an app with expo for two months now testing with IOS only. My app runs multiple database async functions at an instance, i never had issues testing it on IOS but as soon as i started testing it on android, everthing works fine for a moment then i get this error even when im trying to perform only one databse function  [Error: Call to function 'NativeDatabase.prepareAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException]. has anyone experienced this or have a solution to it
i tried looking for solutions online but nothings solves my issues

I was facing this issue on Android, never tested my app on iOS. And was able to solve it by

closing db connection after query by calling db.closeSync();
Reducing number of concurrent db queries.


Thank you, i did something similar to this and it worked. Every time I caught the error, i closed the database connection and then reopened it. Unfortunately my app has to run multiple db queries at an instance
